# Need to verify Autommaper implemented correctly in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have implemented Automapper in my MVC project but not sure if it is been done correctly. I am currently using Entity Framework Database First Approach and retrieving data using stored  procedures. As you would be aware Entity Framework creates complex type object which is a wrapper around Stored Procedures.So I have created two classes for mapping purpose. One is used in the repository class to map the complex type to Entity class and second is the viewmodel that is used to map the entity class to view model in the controller. I havent explicitly mapped my entity class to viewmodel in the controller. So I am wondering how is the data bound to the grid as the grid is expecting viewmodel. I am looking forward for suggestions in terms of the approach that I have taken.

```
spGetUserProfileByUserProfileID_Result - Complex type object
UserProfile                            - Entity class.
UserProfileViewModel                   - ViewModel
```

**AutoMapperConfiguration Class**

```
  public static void Configure()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().OfType<Assembly>().ToArray();
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            cfg.AddProfiles(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
            .Where(
            a =>
               a.FullName.EndsWith("Mapping"))));
        }
```

**Mapping class**

```
public class DomainToModelMapping : Profile
    {
        public DomainToModelMapping()
        {

            CreateMap<spGetUserProfileByUserProfileID_Result, UserProfile>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<UserProfileViewModel, UserProfile>().ReverseMap();

        }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
 public List<UserProfile> GetUserProfileById(int id)
        {
            if (MCRHelper.UserValidate() == 1)
            {
                var userProfiles = db.spGetUserProfileByUserProfileID(id);


                return Mapper.Map<List<UserProfile>>(userProfiles);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult UserProfile_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var response = mcrRepository.GetUserProfileById(0).ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

If I add the following , to my controller to map to viewmodel, I get an error  Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
DataSourceResult -> UserProfile
Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult -> CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.UserProfile

```
var userProfile = mcrRepository.GetUserProfileById(0).ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(userProfile), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to return the viewmodel instead of the entity model from your controller using Automapper, then use [Automapper Queryable Extensions](https://blog.falafel.com/i-love-queryableextensions/):

```
using Automapper.QueryableExtensions;
...
public JsonResult UserProfile_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var users = mcrRepository.GetUserProfileById(0).Project().To<UserProfileViewModel>();
    var response = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I get a red squiggly under Project(). Looks like my version of automapper doesnt support. I am currently using the latest version of automapper

Comment: I made this change and looks like it works    var users = mcrRepository.GetUserProfileById(0).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<UserProfileViewModel>();  Is this right

Comment: Yes, mine was for Automapper 3, but the syntax changed with version 4 and above. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: I am marking the answer as you have shown me the concept